# How to execute and read 2 terminal commands in one process on MacOS in Java

Tags: macos, android-studio, kotlin, command-line, terminal

I am trying to build a Android Studio Plugin which allows me to copy my changed files (Git) to my Clipboard. I am able to get the root path in which the .git file is located. Then I want to execute the command `git diff --name-only` in this path. Therefore i have to execute `cd <path>` at first. Im able to execute one after the other but not booth with the `&&` operator f.e.. Then there is nothing in the input stream. Is it because I am currently working on a Mac which requires other commands? I searched several hours for a solution but nothing seems to works.

Here is my approach:

```
class MyAction: AnAction() {

    override fun actionPerformed(event: AnActionEvent) {
        println("Action Performed")


        val path = ModuleRootManager.getInstance(ModuleManager.getInstance(event.project!!).modules[0]).contentRoots[0].path
        println("Path: $path")

        try {
            runCommand(path, "git diff --name-only")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("Path is incorrect")
        }

    }

    private fun runCommand(path: String, command: String) {
        val rt = Runtime.getRuntime()
        val pathCommand = "cd $path "

        val proc = rt.exec(pathCommand + "&& " + command)

        printInput(proc)
    }

    private fun printInput(proc: Process) {
        printProcessInput(proc)
        printProcessError(proc)
    }

    private fun printProcessInput(proc: Process) {
        println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n")
        printStream(proc.inputStream)
    }
    private fun printProcessError(proc: Process) {
        println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n")
        printStream(proc.errorStream)
    }

    private fun printStream(stream: InputStream) {
        val stdInput = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
        var s: String?
        while (stdInput.readLine().also { s = it } != null) {
            println(s)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If you want to navigate to a directory and execute a command there you can use ProcessBuilder and define the directory like this:

```
private fun runProcess(path: String): Process {
        val file = File(path)
        val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder()

        return processBuilder.command("git", "diff", "--name-only")
            .directory(file)
            .start()
    }
```